# UICollectionView didselect and double tap conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

There are two actions I tried to do.

1. Single tap which is select the cell to push to a new view controller.
2. Double tap to animate the cell.

I registered a double tap gesture and set doubleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan to ture. The single tap action is just a segue from cell to another viewcontroller.

However, there is a 0.5s delay if user single tap the cell to move to another view. The problem is the system wait for double tap gesture. If I remove the delaysTouchesBegan, it only recognize the did select cell function.

How can I reduce the delay?

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a view (V) with UICollectionView (CV) inside it. Add double tap gesture to the V with settings:

```
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
doubleTap.delaysTouchesBegan = true
doubleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = true
```

Implement the `didSelect` of the CV.

It would be work separately the didSelect and the double tap. However because of `delaysTouchesBegan` it would be the delay before `didSelect` would fire.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line
 tapgesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;